# How to pass an n-dim Eigen tensor to a function?

Tags: c++, eigen, tensor

I'm looking to make a loss function that can take 2 tensors of any dimensions as parameters, but the dimensions of tensor 1 (t1) and tensor (t2) must match. Below are the templates that I tried to use to can pass the tensors into the function. I was thinking that T would be a type and N would model the number of indexes possible without explicitly writing a type for infinitely possible tensor dimensions.

loss.h

```cpp
#include <iostream>

namespace Loss {
    template<class T, std::size_t N>
    void loss(Eigen::Tensor<T, N, 0>& predicted, Eigen::Tensor<T, N, 0>& actual) {
        std::cout << "Loss::loss() not implemented" << std::endl;
    };
};
```

main.cpp

```cpp
#include "loss.h"
int main() {

    Eigen::Tensor<double, 3> t1(2, 3, 4);
    Eigen::Tensor<double, 3> t2(2, 3, 4);

    t1.setZero();
    t2.setZero();
  
    Loss::loss(t1, t2);

    return 0;
}
```

The type error that I get before compiling from my editor:

> no instance of function template "Loss::loss" matches the argument list -- argument types are: (Eigen::Tensor<double, 3, 0, Eigen::DenseIndex>, Eigen::Tensor<double, 3, 0, Eigen::DenseIndex>

And this is the message I get once I compile (unsuccessfully):

> note: candidate template ignored: substitution failure [with T = double]: deduced non-type template argument does not have the same type as the corresponding template parameter ('int' vs 'std::size_t' (aka 'unsigned long'))
> void loss(Eigen::Tensor<T, N, 0>& predicted, Eigen::Tensor<T, N, 0>& actual) {
> ^
> 1 error generated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is pointing out the type of the non-type template parameter is `size_t`, but in the declaration of `t1` and `t2` the value of that parameter is 3, which has type `int`. This mismatch makes the template argument deduction fail.

You can fix this by changing the type of the non-type template parameter to `int`

```
template<class T, int N>
void loss( // ...
```

or just let it be deduced

```
template<class T, auto N>
void loss( // ...
```

Comment: This works perfectly! How does auto differ from int? Does it infer the type? From a quick Google search it seems like it detects it somehow.

Comment: @SonsofKings Yes, that's correct, it deduces the type.

Answer (score 0):

number literals are signed integers, and you’ve specified the number type of your template as `size_t` Which is unsigned. So the types don’t match. Try `Eigen::Tensor<double, 3u> …` in your main program to use unsigned literals.